# LaCie 10TB external drive slows over time

Tags: external-disk, disk-space

I have a LaCie 10TB drive for storing photos and almost filled it completed. I notice Lightroom runs very slow and I suspect it there is an issue with the file structure. Does the file index table get very large or is there a lot of fragmentation that might be causing this? I've run DiskWarrior and permissions but not a great difference. I'm using a MacBook Pro 2015 so it doesn't have a lot of grunt compared to the newer models.

Comment: Do you know the file system format you have chosen?

Comment: OS X Extended (Journaled)